# Is it possible to apply a quantum gate to a density marix from a partial trace?

Tags: density-matrix, linear-algebra

To apply a gate(matrix) to a 2 qubit partial trace(4x4 matrix) I have this function:

```
@jit(nopython = True)   

    def evolverho(rho:np.ndarray,gate : np.ndarray):
        gate_transpose = gate.transpose()    
        # dot same as matmul but for numba
        m = np.dot(gate, rho) 
        m = np.dot(m, np.conjugate(gate_transpose)) 
        return m
```

If I apply a cx (control=0, target=1) to a 5 qubit, and then trace it in pairs [0,1] [0,2] [0,3][0,4] and [1,2] [1,3] [1,4] will change. If I evolve the pair [0,1] with the cx above, the result will be the same, but the other pairs need to ve evolved with another matrixs becuase in them only one qubit changes. 
Ok, I have another method that tries to find that matrices, that works not so good. So my question is does that gates matrixs exists?.

Comment: So, to be clear (and simplify the problem): if you have a 3-qubit system, qubits 0,1,2, you want to be able to apply a controlled not between qubits 0 and 1. You want to know the reduced density matrix of qubits 0,2 (tracing out qubit 1), and you want to know if you can calculate it *just* starting from the reduced density matrix of qubits 0 and 2 (tracing out qubit 1) from *before* the gate?

Comment: If so, this is clearly impossible, because it the outcome definitely depends on the state of qubit 1.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I'm trying to do. The indexs changed in the rho[0,2] are [1, 4, 11, 14] (for bloch q0) and [3, 6, 9, 12] (not bloches used), so qubit 1 in rho[0,2] is never changed. Here is a script that shows the changes github.com/jesusmontera/varios/blob/… and here is a script that tries to find the gate 2x2 in numba brute force https://github.com/jesusmontera/varios/blob/df94b4a62b3ee9cab70226d5cdfe88d8f7636413/gatefinderclass.py#L208